Voltage detected in siding nails and foil insulation
Background: I am in the process of installing siding on my home. Currently I am removing the old siding from one side and I'm trying to identify wire locations so I can take extra precautions when nailing in those areas (nails are penetrating 3/4" into the stud).
The issue: I used my low voltage detector and noticed I was getting a slight beep on some exposed nails and on the foil-backed insulation in one area. I used a multimeter and got a reading of 3V on the nails and 10V on the foil insulation. When I turn two breakers off, the voltage reading goes away. I'm thinking a nail may have hit a wire nearby and voltage is traveling through the foil backed insulation or maybe there has been voltage leaking to this wall for years since I haven't done any work on this side of the house yet.
I'm at a loss of where to begin troubleshooting this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I have a seasoned electrician coming next week to help me troubleshoot, but I'd like to have a better idea of what is going on and if I should open walls beforehand. Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Sounds like induced voltage to me. A little knowledge is a dangerous thing. Note that 3/4" doesn't warrant such extreme caution unless you've encountered improperly installed wiring suggesting that there's a concern. Is that the case? Nothing should be within at least 1-1/4" of the stud face.

I was wondering if it was a concern or possibly detecting induced voltage.  A wire was hit initially and repaired by the electrician, but it was due to longer nails, which have since been changed.  The first incident has caused me to be overly cautious for the remainder of the project.  Do you think it is possible there is a nail that pierced a wire causing this low voltage across this section of the wall?

3 or 10 volts seem more like phantom voltage reading.  What most for the lower/mid cost meters will pick up.  Might just be the foil is around a junction/light box.  What do the two breakers you turned off, power?

One is for lights and outlets upstairs and the other one is for outlets downstairs, but both are outlets/wires on the same wall.

Best to put the info about actually hitting a wire with longer nails into the question.

Thanks. Yes, nail into wire incident was on the other side of the house, and was corrected within the first few rows of siding. Could powering off the circuits and testing each outlet/light for continuity with a long wire to the outside foil insulation rule out induced voltage?

Is there any way to check to see if it is simply induced voltage from nearby wiring?
